# ${arr[@]} in sed command

Tags: shell, sed

```
#!/bin/sh

arr=(
    a
    b
    c
)
sed "s/abc/${arr[@]}/" file
```

sh -x this_script.sh show the result with error:

```
+ arr=(a b c)
+ sed s/abc/a b c/ file
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

it should be:

```
+ sed 's/abc/a b c/' file
```

there's already double quotation in this script, why need declare a variable to make it work:

```
 x=${arr[@]}
 sed "s/abc/$x/" file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${arr[*]}` instead of `${arr[@]}` to be treated it like a single string:

```
sed "s/abc/${arr[*]}/" <<< "abc"

a b c
```